# Several Tasks manipulating on same Object

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

So was I just doing some experiments with Task class in c# and the following thing happens.

Here is the method I call

```
static async Task<List<int>> GenerateList(long size, int numOfTasks)
{
    var nums = new List<int>();

    Task[] tasks = new Task[numOfTasks];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => nums.Add(Rand.Nex())); // Rand is a ThreadLocal<Random>
    }

    for (long i = 0; i < size; i += numOfTasks)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    return nums;
}
```

I call this method like this

```
var nums = GenerateList(100000000, 10).Result;
```

before I used Tasks generation took like 4-5 seconds. after I implemented this method like this if I pass 10-20 number of tasks the time of generation is lowered to 1,8-2,2 seconds but the thing it the `List` which is return by the method has `numOfTask` number of Elements in it so in this case `List` of ten numbers is returned. May be I'm writing something wrong.   What can be the problem here. Or may be there is another solution to It. All I want it many task to add numbers in the same list so the generation time would be at least twice faster. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WhenAll` does not run the tasks; it just (asynchronously) waits for them to complete. Your code is only creating 10 tasks, so that's why you're only getting 10 numbers. Also, as @Mauro pointed out, `List<T>.Add` is not threadsafe.

If you want to do parallel computation, then use `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ, not `async`:

```
static List<int> GenerateList(int size, int numOfTasks)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, size)
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(numOfTasks)
        .Select(_ => Rand.Value.Next())
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Stephen, you are only creating 10 tasks.

Also, I believe the `Add` operation on the generic list is not thread safe. You should use a locking mechanism or, if you are targeting framework 4 or newer, use [thread-safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) .

Comment: I don't see any code in the question that would close over the loop variable.

Answer (score -1):

you are adding to the list in the following loop which runs for only 10 times

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => nums.Add(Rand.Nex())); // Rand is a ThreadLocal<Random>
    }
```

you can instead do

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = new Task(() => nums.Add(Rand.Nex()));
    }
```

Comment: What I want to do is to have suppose 10 task that will add numbers to list and run them in the seconds task

Comment: can I run task array without running every of them distinctively in loop ?

Comment: This won't work, it creates unstarted `Task`s and then never starts them. And even if you do that, you can only start each `Task` once.

Comment: @svick - i know that.. i was just telling the questioner how to make tasks without starting them

Comment: 1. So, why didn't you say so? The text of your answer doesn't say that. 2. How does that answer the question ?

Comment: i pointed out a problem in the code. Text of my answer exactly says this. anyways thats for the help.. ill updated my ans soon